# conditionally remove elements in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of Characters named `Vector`, this is the output:

```
[1] "140222" "140207" "0" "140214" "140228" "140322" "140307" "140419" "140517" "140719" "141018" "150117" "160115"
```

I want to conditionally remove the only element different to the others, in this case the `0`.

I tried this approach but it seems not working:

```
for (i in 1:length(Vector) {
    if (nchar(Vector[i]) <=3) 
    {remove(Vector[i])}
}
```

The error is:

> Error in remove(Vector[i]) : 
>         ... must contain names or character strings".

Comment: If your vector is called `tmp`, just do `tmp[-which(nchar(tmp) < 6)]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use a loop for this. This will do what you want:

`Vector <- Vector[nchar(Vector) > 3]`

If you wanted to specifically remove the "0", you would do this:

`Vector <- Vector[Vector != "0"]`

The error is caused because you're using `remove` on an element inside `Vector`, instead of on an object. In other words, `remove` can remove all of `Vector` from memory, but not elements of it. Same is true for other objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using R interactively (otherwise it's less recommended - see here: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)), you can also write:

```
subset(Vector, nchar(Vector) >3)
```

Comment: `subset()` should not be used in a non-interactive environment.

Comment: @TARehman; your down-vote is really not constructive. 1/ The question doesn't mention it's a non-interactive environment. 2/ I think it's helpful to show a beginner the different options the language has to offer.

Comment: Good edit, and I hesitated somewhat given the age of the question, but I figured that if I stumbled across it while trying to find something, so could another user.